# mysql service gets timed out while starting

Tags: mysql, mariadb, apparmor

Starting mysql gets timed out. I am not sure why.

I have gone through the log files as suggested only to learn that it's getting timed out, but couldn't understand why. I have even tried reinstalling the lamp stack and yet this is the same result.

```
toor@linux:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
[....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service
Job for mariadb.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
failed!


toor@linux:~$ systemctl status mariadb.service
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.1.37 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Thu 2019-03-28 18:52:25 IST; 1min 13s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 14867 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, stat
  Process: 14790 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`
  Process: 14785 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCC
  Process: 14783 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCE
 Main PID: 14867 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "MariaDB server is down"
lines 1-11/11 (END)
```

I tried pasting the result of journalctl -xe but the can't submit it since there is quite an amount of code in there. So here's the [output](https://pastebin.com/BPJgeJzK).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**sudo aa-status** shows you what apparmor is doing.

**sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils** adds a few commands that make the apparmor profiles easier.

**sudo aa-complain /usr/sbin/mysqld** turns the profile from "enforce" to complain.

**sudo service apparmor reload** restarts apparmor, and voila... **sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start** to restart server.

Comment: apparmor wasn't installed, so I installed it and activated it as per debian wiki. Although sudo aa-complain /usr/sbin/mysqld threw a message saying that the profile is empty, everything seems to be working now.

Comment: Could you please explain 'more' your solution ? Why does it fix the issue ?